RewriteRule with multiple subdirectories in Apache 2.4
Here is the translation:

I have a server that hosts an Angular application and a PHP API within it. However, within my application, I have directories for the application's localization, and inside each one, there is an index.html file.
My directory structure is organized as follows:

Project root in en-US: /var/www/html/my-app
Project i18n in en-GB: /var/www/html/my-app/en-GB
Project i18n in es-ES: /var/www/html/my-app/es-ES
Project i18n in es-MX: /var/www/html/my-app/es-MX
Project i18n in pt-BR: /var/www/html/my-app/pt-BR
Project i18n in pt-PT: /var/www/html/my-app/pt-PT
PHP API root called by the application: /var/www/html/my-app/api

Within the .htaccess file at the root (/var/www/html/my-app), I have the following configuration, which makes it so that if an address is not a file, the index.html file is loaded. However, this only works for the root index.html. If I am browsing at example.com/es-ES and refresh the browser, it redirects me back to the general root, not to the index.html file in the es-ES directory.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.html
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>

How can I make the .htaccess file take the predefined directories into account?
